# HTML: Textarea reset

Tags: jquery, html

When I press enter, I want to reset the textarea, but when I do that there is a problem.
Example:
[image: example]
'Typ hier om te chatten' is the placeholder. When I typ something an hit enter:

[image: example 2]
Now it is focused, but I still need to click to type again, how to do this automaticly?

Code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){

    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13' && $( "#message" ).val().trim() != ""){
        socket.emit("sendMessage", { value: $( "#message" ).val() });
        $( "#message" ).remove();
        $( "#messagesBoard" ).append("<textarea autofocus maxlength=\"308\"id=\"message\" placeholder=\"Typ hier om te chatten\"></textarea>");
        $( "#message" ).click(); << WONT WORK
    }

});
```

Comment: Why dont you just add a jsfiddle instead of images.

Comment: Your problem is removing the content of focusing the textarea? Not clear for me.

Comment: I always prefer `$("#message").trigger("click")`. I know `click()` should work, but it might act as event handler getter.

Comment: @Alvaro, my problem is the click thingy.I still need to click when I want to type.

Comment: @user3144435 why the title of the question says "reset"?

Comment: Because I want to reset the textarea to the placeholder thing.

Answer (score 1):

can you try like this , which will set focus on `textarea` once it get created

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $( "#message").find('textarea').focus();
}, 10);
```